# nesting a component and need to get a property value to parent from said component and set another

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

I've got a file upload component that I'm spinning up multiple instances of file component instances inside based on a user's file list selection.

Once the user has loaded n number of files into the upload container, they have the option of adding some description text for each file component independently which I'm just setting as a string property inside the file component and two-way binding to it from the HTML with `ngModel`.  On the parent component there is a button that will kick off the upload process.  I'm trying to loop over my file component instances I've pushed to an array and the description property is not accessible from the parent inside my loop.

That's problem one.  Problem two is I also want to set a boolean property on the child component (isUploading) so I can provide some user feedback that that particular file is in progress.  Right now I'm just trying to show a `ProgressSpinner` for that child file component specifically.  But it's not auto updating based on my updating the reference inside my loop in the parent component.

I'm sure it's something I'm missing with events or the like but I'm struggling putting it together and can't find a good resource for my scenario.

Here is the parent (file upload component) ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatFileComponent } from './mat-file.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'mat-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './mat-file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mat-file-upload.component.css']
})
export class MatFileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  fileList: MatFileComponent[]
  @Input() apiEndpoint: string;
  @Input() parentContainerId: string;
  hasFiles: boolean;
  bucketDescription: string;
  addFilesToList(files: File[]): void {
    this.fileList = [];
    for (let file of files) {
      // generate the file component here in code then bind them in the loop in the HTML
      let fileComponent = new MatFileComponent()
      fileComponent.fileData = file;
      fileComponent.fileDescription = '';
      fileComponent.fileName = file.name;
      fileComponent.fileType = file.type;
      this.fileList.push(fileComponent);
    }
    this.hasFiles = true;
  }
  startUpload(): void {
    if (!this.fileList || !this.fileList.length || !this.hasFiles) {
      return;
    }
    for (let fileComponent of this.fileList) {
      console.log("desc: " + fileComponent.fileDescription);
      fileComponent.isUploading = true;
    }
  } 
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Here is its supporting HTML:

```
<input type="file" hidden name="addToList" [class]="ng-hide" #file multiple id="addToList" (change)="addFilesToList(file.files)" />
<label for="addToList" class="mat-raised-button">
  Select Files To Upload
</label>
<div *ngIf="fileList && fileList.length">
  <mat-file *ngFor="let file of fileList"
            [fileName]="file.fileName"
            [fileData]="file.fileData"
            [fileType]="file.fileType"
            [projectId]="projectId"></mat-file>
</div>
<mat-card class="card-footer" *ngIf="hasFiles">
  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput required placeholder="*Required* file bucket description..." [(ngModel)]="bucketDescription"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button class="mat-raised-button submit-form" (click)="startUpload()" [disabled]="!bucketDescription || !bucketDescription.length > 0">
    Upload Files
  </button>
</mat-card>
```

Here is the child (file component) ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IFile } from '../Interfaces/IFile';

@Component({
  selector: 'mat-file',
  templateUrl: './mat-file.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mat-file.component.css']
})
export class MatFileComponent implements OnInit, IFile {
  @Input() fileName: string;
  @Input() fileData: File;
  @Input() fileType: string;
  @Input() projectId: number;
  public isUploading: boolean;
  fileDescription: string;

  imageLocalUrl: any;
  componentLoaded: boolean = false

  constructor() { }
  get isFileImage(): boolean {
    return this.fileType.toLowerCase().indexOf('image') > -1;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileData);
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      this.imageLocalUrl = reader.result;
    }
    this.componentLoaded = true;
  }
}
```

And its supporting HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="componentLoaded" class="file-card">
  <mat-card class="mat-card-image">
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{ fileName }}</mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-content>
      <div *ngIf="imageLocalUrl && isFileImage" class="image-thumb file-thumb" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' +imageLocalUrl+ ')'"></div>
      <mat-form-field>
        <textarea matInput placeholder="*Optional* file description..." [(ngModel)]="fileDescription"></textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
    <div *ngIf="(isUploading)" class="loading-indicator-shade">
      <mat-progress-spinner class="loading-indicator" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-spinner>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

And is how I spin up the file upload component with a tag directive:

```
<mat-file-upload [apiEndpoint]="'/api/ProjectApi/UploadFile'" [parentContainerId]="projectId"></mat-file-upload>
```

I apologize for all of this code vomit, but wanted to paint a very clear picture. I'm sure both items are something simple, but I'm stumped.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Add @Output() to your child component, so that it can emit back the changes to the parent component.

```
export class MatFileComponent implements OnInit, IFile {
   @Output() uploadComplete = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

   ...

   onComplete() {
      this.uploadComplete.next(true);
   }

   ... 
}
```

Now listen for this event in the parent component.

```
<div *ngIf="fileList && fileList.length">
  <mat-file *ngFor="let file of fileList"
            [fileName]="file.fileName"
            [fileData]="file.fileData"
            [fileType]="file.fileType"
            [projectId]="projectId">
            (onComplete)="handleCompleteEvent($event)"</mat-file>
</div>
```

and in the parent component introduce the above method to handle the event *emitted* from the child component.

.ts

```
handleCompleteEvent(status: boolean) {
   if (status) {
      // do something here...
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for.  The parent component will be the one responsible for doing the uploading so it needs to notify the child when it has started the upload (and finished).  This looks to me like you've got it so the child is sending notifications to the parent.  Incidentally, I was able to use this approach to settle my other question in my OP.  How can I change a property on the child component from the parent so that `*ngIf` will show or hide depending on the parent's actions?

Comment: You can add `@Input()` to the child component and then pass in this value from the parent component.

Comment: As I mentioned in my other post you helped me with yesterday, I'm pretty new to angular and after a quick code review this morning with a fresh mind, I realize where I'm going wrong.  I'm referencing different instances of my file component that I initialized in code.  What you helped me do yesterday was to reinitialize them in HTML with the directive.  So this leads to a totally new, but still on topic question.  Is there a way to reference the collection of file component instances that is spun up from the `*ngFor` inside the HTML piece of the file upload component from its code file?

Comment: As per my knowledge - no (at least not in html). Probably you need to *restructure* your components better? The answer above lets you receive data from the child -> parent (And I think that answers a part of your question?) Not sure if this is what you are asking but if you want a reference of the child in the parent, you can use the @ViewChild decorator.

Comment: I didn't see your message until now after I did a big refactor.  I got a little creative using your `EventEmitter` approach.  What I have works perfectly.  I will post an answer with my solution because it's a lot to type into this comment.  I'm not sure that it's the best pattern, but it works quite well for my scenario.  I'd be interested to see if you think there are any major flaws with it that I've overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

based on Nicholas' answer, I came up with this solution.  I'm firing an `EventEmitter` in my `ngOnInit()` of the initialization and passing `this` back to the parent file upload component.  In that component's class, I just add the reference to the child component to an array which is giving me correct access to it's members.

file upload component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatFileComponent } from './mat-file.component';
import { FileUploadService } from '../Services/file-upload.service';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IFile } from '../Interfaces/IFile';

@Component({
  selector: 'mat-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './mat-file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mat-file-upload.component.css']
})
export class MatFileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private fileUploadService: FileUploadService) { }
  matFileComponents: MatFileComponent[] = [];
  fileList: any[];
  @Input() apiEndpoint: string;
  @Input() parentContainerId: string;
  hasFiles: boolean;
  bucketDescription: string;
  bucketId: string = "0";
  uploaded: number = 0;
  errorMessage: string;
  addFilesToList(files: File[]): void {
    this.fileList = [];
    for (let file of files) {
      // generate the file collectoin here then loop over it to create the children in the HTML
      let fileComponent = 
        {
          "fileData": file,
          "fileName": file.name,
          "fileType": file.type
        }
      this.fileList.push(fileComponent);
    }
    this.hasFiles = true;
  }
  addInstanceToCollection(matFileComponent: MatFileComponent): void {
    this.matFileComponents.push(matFileComponent);
  }
  startUpload(): void {
    for (let matFileComponent of this.matFileComponents) {
      // just for testing, make sure the isUploading works and log the description to the console to make sure it's here
      // hell, let's just log the whole instance ;)  The file upload service will be called from here
      matFileComponent.isUploading = true;
      console.log(matFileComponent.fileDescription);
      console.log(matFileComponent);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

its supporting HTML:

```
<input type="file" hidden name="addToList" [class]="ng-hide" #file multiple id="addToList" (change)="addFilesToList(file.files)" />
<label for="addToList" class="mat-raised-button">
  Select Files To Upload
</label>
<div *ngIf="fileList && fileList.length" >
  <mat-file *ngFor="let file of fileList"
            [fileName]="file.fileName"
            [fileData]="file.fileData"
            [fileType]="file.fileType"
            [projectId]="projectId"
            (instanceCreatedEmitter)="addInstanceToCollection($event)"></mat-file>
</div>
<mat-card class="card-footer" *ngIf="hasFiles">
  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput required placeholder="*Required* file bucket description..." [(ngModel)]="bucketDescription"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button class="mat-raised-button submit-form" (click)="startUpload()" [disabled]="!bucketDescription || !bucketDescription.length > 0">
    Upload Files
  </button>
</mat-card>
```

file component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { IFile } from '../Interfaces/IFile';

@Component({
  selector: 'mat-file',
  templateUrl: './mat-file.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mat-file.component.css']
})
export class MatFileComponent implements OnInit, IFile {
  @Input() fileName: string;
  @Input() fileData: File;
  @Input() fileType: string;
  @Input() projectId: number;
  @Input() isUploading: boolean = false;
  @Output() instanceCreatedEmitter = new EventEmitter<MatFileComponent>();
  public fileDescription: string;

  imageLocalUrl: any;
  componentLoaded: boolean = false

  constructor() { }
  get isFileImage(): boolean {
    return this.fileType.toLowerCase().indexOf('image') > -1;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileData);
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      this.imageLocalUrl = reader.result;
    }
    this.componentLoaded = true;
    // now emit this instance back to the parent so they can add it to their collection
    this.instanceCreatedEmitter.emit(this);
  }
}
```

its supporting HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="componentLoaded" class="file-card">
  <mat-card class="mat-card-image">
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{ fileName }}</mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-content>
      <div *ngIf="imageLocalUrl && isFileImage" class="image-thumb file-thumb" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' +imageLocalUrl+ ')'"></div>
      <mat-form-field>
        <textarea matInput placeholder="*Optional* file description..." [(ngModel)]="fileDescription"></textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
    <div *ngIf="isUploading" class="loading-indicator-shade">
      <mat-progress-spinner class="loading-indicator" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-spinner>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

This solved both of my problems in the OP because now I have references to the actual component whose properties I need to hook into.

I did read about the @ViewChild option as well Nicholas, but I had already written this and unless you tell me that this solution is terrible for one reason or another, I'm gonna take the "if it ain't broke..." road here.

Comment: IMO, the problem with this is that now you are tying the `eventEmitter` to all instances of `MatFileComponent` which is not considered the best practise. Maybe, you need to revisit the design of your components. The `MatFileUploadComponent` should be responsible for uploading just one file. Then you can manage a list of files in another component say `MatFileListUploadComponent`? Now possibly from this component you could loop and call other `MatFileComponent` in a loop. Or even better delegate this whole uploading functionality to a service.

Comment: Anyway, that can be considered as *subjective* // *opinionated*, etc. An upvote for my troubles?

Comment: how about 5, 1 on the answer, 4 on your comments ;)  thanks so much again.

Comment: @NicholasK curious why you think the `MatFileUploadComponent` component should only be responsible for one file?  That layer is broken out (single files) at the `MatFileComponent`.  The purpose of the `MatFileUploadComponent` is to be able to handle the full collection.  It can certainly do just one file, but the way it's architechted right now it's already capable of one or many.  I'm sorta lost why you think I need to add a 3rd component for just the lists part....

Comment: Haha, thanks for that (Unrelated - Just the upvote to the answer increases rep). Angular components should be as light-weight as possible. So all the heavy lifting should be delegated to a service. IMO, I feel that `MatFileComponent` should be responsible for uploading each file, that way you have a better control over each file from where ever you invoke it.